# jQuery .load() - Append two elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery .load() method and I want to append two elements. I can load them separately but not together, how can I load one under the other ?

```
$('#left').load('page1.php #div1');
$('#left').load('page2.php #div2');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have two elements inside `#left` as placeholders:

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="left-top"></div>
    <div id="left-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And in js

```
$('#left-top').load('page1.php #div1');
$('#left-bottom').load('page2.php #div2');
```

Comment: Works great, simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

if the order of loaded `divs` are important you can do:

```
$("#left").load('page1.php #div1', function() {
  $("#left").append($.load('page1.php #div2'));
});
```

this way the inner function that loades `#div2` will run after the first `.load` has finished